# wordpress search bar is overfloating

Tags: html, css

I add a search enigne field in my header, here is the css code:

```
.header-wrap h2{
    min-height:63px;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    top:29px;
    left:0px;
}

/* Link */
.header-wrap .site-title a{
    display:inline-block;
    min-height:85px;
    padding-top:22px;
}

/* Input */
#menu-header form input[type=text]{
    position:relative;
    top:16px;
    left:-11px;
    z-index:0;
}

/* Label */
#menu-header form label{
    position:relative;

}
```

the problem is that i have this field over floating like in the screenshot

With blue arrow is the normal search engine field and with green arrow is another field that is over floating.

[image]

How can i get rid off this?

Comment: Have you place search code two times in that page?

Comment: The point is that i add the search enigne via a plugin, so i assume that cannot be a possibility off double code placing. So i believe that something is pushing the field and makes all this mess.